# Displaying Data from an Eloquent collection with Relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I'm trying to get data from an Eloquent query as follows:

`$submission->find($id)->first()->with('user', 'clientform')->get();`

I'm sending the submission to the view and attempting to access properties from the `user` model like so:

```
{{ $submission->clientform->name }}
```

However, Laravel is throwing the following error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$clientform
```

What am I doing wrong with the way my query is formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overdoing it!

Let's break it down:

```
$submission->find($id);
```

Will return an instance of the model which corresponds to the entry having the primary key of `$id`.

```
$submission->find($id)->first();
```

This is an unncessary repetition; the `find` method already gives you a single entry, no need to call `first` on it.

```
$submission->find($id)->first()->with('user', 'clientform');
```

This is where you start going the wrong way; when calling with on a model, Laravel will transform that model into a query builder again, even though it was already resolved by calling `find`.

```
$submission->find($id)->first()->with('user', 'clientform')->get();
```

Finally, the `get` method resolves the builder into a `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, regardless of the number of entries found (i.e. it could be a `Collection` of only one item). It's worth noting, though, that your query will most likely have been fully reset by calling with. It would be the same as instantiating a fresh `Submission` model and building your query with it. That means you're probably using a collection of *all* your submission entries, not just the one with `$id`.

Long story short, this is what you want:

```
$submission->with('user', 'clientform')->find($id);
```

It will fetch the matching `$id`, with the `user` and `clientform` relations eager-loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation! That solved all of my issues.